# Finding lists of files with specific permissions

Tags: bash, shell, permissions

I looked into the find command and came up with `find . -maxdepth 1 -perm 521 > test.txt` to output the permissions to a text file, but is it possible to do it just using, for example, simple commands like `ls`?  As far as I know, `ls` can't seem to reference permissions specifically so I can't give it a certain permission set to look for.

Is there any other straightforward method I may be overlooking?

Comment: What is un-simple about find? It is a bog-standard Unix command.

Comment: if you remove the `> test.txt` part, the output will just show on the screen like `ls`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you are searching something like:

```
ls -l | grep '^.r-x-w-r--'
```

Note that for files with matching permissions whose name contains newline characters, that will only report the first lines of those file names. It could also give false positives if there were files named like `foobar<newline>xr-x-w-r--` (or symlinks to files named like that). It's generally wrong to process file names with line-based utilities like `grep`. You could work around that here by using the `-q` option which tells `ls` to render non-printable characters (including newline) as `?`.

IMHO, there is no tool better than `find` to search files. It is simple, straightforward and very powerful. Using `find ... -exec ...` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`, you can easily manipulate, in many ways, files you find. I do not think that you can find any better general purpose tool.

Answer (score 2):

`find` is the straightforward method. If you use zsh, you can use its [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `f` (or a bunch of other qualifiers to characterise permission bits individually).

```
printf '%s\n' *(f521)
```

Or

```
printf '%s\n' *(f[u=rx,g=w,o=x])
```

To use the symbolic notation (in case it's the octal notation that puts you off). Add the `D` glob qualifier if you also want hidden files to be considered.

Note that the symbolic notation can also be used with `find`.

```
find . -perm u=rx,g=w,o=x
```

And most `find` implementations have a `-ls` predicate to give you an output similar to that of `ls -l`. For those that don't you can always use `-exec ls -ld -- {} +` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `find` you might use standard tools like `stat` and `awk` as follows:

```
shopt -s dotglob
awk '/^521/ {print $2}' <(stat -c "%a %n" *) > test.txt
```

You need to set the `dotglob` option if hidden files should be included in the expansion of `*`.

Comment: `stat` is anything but a standard tool. There are many incompatible implementations of such an utility. Many systems don't have one. Yours seems to be the GNU implementation (or possibly the busybox one which emulates the GNU one) which is incompatible with the zsh builtin one or the BSD one.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ls -l | grep -e "-rw-r--r--"
```

Use `-e` for `grep` it will list all the files with the desired permission.

Comment: This would also get any filename that happens to have that string in its name.

Comment: What’s significant about `-e`, apart from introducing the pattern (since it starts with `-`)?